# Keep one special character using regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string but i need to keep the "-" and remove everything else

```
string my_String = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z\._]", "");
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string my_String = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z\._-]", "");` (notice the `-` at the end) will remove anything which is not a number, English upper or lower case letter, a period and an underscore.

If by *keep the "-" and remove everything else* you mean keep only the dashes, you would need to use this: `string my_String = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^-]", "");`.

Comment: no i wanna remove every single special character except the dash if u can

Comment: @AnthonyG: Then the first answer should work for you. It will keep the numbers, letters, periods, underscores and dashes. Anything else is removed. I do not know if you also want to remove white space characters, which is what the current expression does.